# What's the meaning of null ! in TypeScript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have seen `null !` many times in source code of Angular. What's the meaning of the following `!` mark?

examples:

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L221

  ```
  private navigations = new BehaviorSubject<NavigationParams>(null !);
  ```
- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L357

  ```
  this.locationSubscription = null !;
  ```

Comment: Code samples have been added. I don't think this question is duplicated with the provided one. `null !` is not used when dereferencing a member here.

Comment: The answer to that question explains it, it applies to any expression, not only dereferencing a member: "this expression cannot be null or undefined here". So the real question is, how null can not be null? The answer: it can't, it's just that something is declared as non-nullable, but it's necessary to assign null to it in appropriate circumstances (in second example - in the `dispose()` function, to avoid holding on a reference to some memory for example), so non-null assertion operator is used to suppress compiler errors.